# Android : No resource identifier found for attribute 'headerView'

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Using Android Studio, I get this error in my activity layout : `Error:(9) No resource identifier found for attribute 'headerView' in package 'com.merahjambutech.zuki.deteksi'`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.merahjambutech.zuki.deteksi.view.PullToZoomListViewEx
        android:id="@+id/paralax_social_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        app:headerView="@layout/header_parallax_social" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm very sure the layout **header_parallax_social.xml** is available in my project files (res/layout), here's the code of **header_parallax_social**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_parallax_social_new_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_main_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/parallax_social_small" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried to change xmlns:app and anything like that, but still not found solution...

Comment: I think you should use drawable instead of layout .. => `app:headerView="@drawable/header_parallax_social"`

Comment: Or try changing `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`  to `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set custom attribute i.e. headerView for your `Listview` in `attrs.xml` in `values` folder :

**attrs.xml**

```
 <resources>
<declare-styleable name="PullToZoomListViewEx">  declare your custom listview class name here
    <attr name="headerView" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
 </resources>
```

By doing this i hope `app:headerView="@layout/header_parallax_social"` will not show any error but to show header view in a listview you have to do some changes in your custom Listview class and it should looks like

```
public class PullToZoomListViewEx  extends ListView{
private int headerId;
public PullToZoomListViewEx(Context context) {
    super(context);
    }

  public PullToZoomListViewEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      this(context, attrs, 0);

    }

  public PullToZoomListViewEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int  defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PullToZoomListViewEx, defStyle, defStyle);

        try {
            headerId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.PullToZoomListViewEx_headerView, View.NO_ID);
            if (headerId != View.NO_ID) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View header = inflater.inflate(headerId, null);
                addHeaderView(header);
            }
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

**or**

If you want to avoid above efforts, You can programmatically set a header view to a Listview like this :

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
   ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header,myListView, false);
//replace  R.layout.header with R.layout.header_parallax_social and  myListView with your listview object
   myListView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

Hope this helps.